# How to format an email that Hotmail / Outlook is happy with?

Tags: php, email, outlook, hotmail

```
$body = 'This is a test';
    $subject = 'Confirmation';
$headers = 'From: Testing Site' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: admin@myserver.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(). "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Delivery-Date: ' . date("r") . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Message-Id: <20140316055950.DA8ED58A13CE@myserver.com>' . "\r\n";

mail("example@hotmail.com", $subject, $body, $headers, "-f admin@myserver.com");
mail("example@gmail.com", $subject, $body, $headers, "-f admin@myserver.com");
```

Emails send fine to Gmail but are always rejected by Hotmail with this error:

> host mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.33.119] said: 550 5.7.0 (COL0-MC5-F28)
>   Message could not be delivered. Please ensure the message is RFC 5322
>   compliant. (in reply to end of DATA command).

Message ID header is generated automatically by the server but it doesn't help to supply one manually either.

Why isn't Hotmail happy?

Mail server has SPF record, reverse DNS, is not blacklisted and passes all checks at mxtoolbox.com.

Comment: is this standalone script? or part of your WordPress?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033694/why-cant-i-send-an-email-to-hotmail?rq=1. Probably worthwhile to check your email server regarding this.

Answer (score 12):

The `From` header is invalid. It must have the following syntax:

```
From: "name" <email-address>
```

In your case:

```
From: "Testing Site" <admin@myserver.com>
```

The same goes for your `Reply-To` header:

```
Reply-To: "Testing Site" <admin@myserver.com>
```

Which you can omit if it's the same as the `From` header (like in your case).

PS: [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) *doesn't* state that the display-name in an address should be quoted. In other words: the following 3 headers should all work:

```
From: "Testing Site" <admin@myserver.com>
From: 'Testing Site' <admin@myserver.com>
From: Testing Site <admin@myserver.com>
```

Comment: The syntax is good, I only forgot to add this to the `$header`. This code works for me: `$header = "from: 'Testing Site' <admin@myserver.com>"`. Thought it might be good to be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WordPress, you can look up plugin for Hotmail/Outlook friendly emailing capability.

However if it is a standalone script you might wanna look into Microsoft's official answer to this query on the URL : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/why-are-the-emails-sent-to-microsoft-account/b64e3e4a-0d93-40c8-8e28-4be849012f9c

In-short Email-Server provider has to fill this form (once) : https://support.live.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl3&ct=eformts&wa=wsignin1.0&scrx=1

In order to get their emails accepted by Hotmail/Outlook.

Comment: Yes a standalone script, but has not has problems delivering to hotmail until recently. I will fill out the form and see if it can be resolved.

Comment: Went through that ordeal just to have microsoft tell me they won't whitelist my i.p but could not say why other than it was automated.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Go to [**SPF record wizard**](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/spfwizard/)

2) create a new SPF record for your DNS domain
3) Add that DNS record to your domain's DNS
4) if you fail somewhere in the process, read the [**detailed SPF record specification**](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/senderid/)

After you complete this process HOTMAIL will be happy with your email.

Comment: OP mentions SPF is place.

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer Yes, my mistake, I should see it before answering, anyway I think the answer is still worth not to be deleted. It may benefit future visitors with the same problem but with no SPF record.

Answer (score 0):

Using the PHPMailer library to send mail instead of the mail() function has finally sorted this problem and is the working solution for me. Answer by Jasper N. Brouwer probably more correctly answers the question though I've not had a chance to try it.